# Location API - Handling NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

After some time of running my application I get a `NullPointerException`when `Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);` is called in the following code below, I'm trying to udnerstand how do I handle this exception to prevent it from crashing my code in the future.

```
public class LocationIntentService extends IntentService {

    public LocationIntentService() {
        super("LocationIntentService");
    }

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        onHandleIntent(intent);
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
        if (location != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location: " + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
            Intent LocationIntent = new Intent("com.xyz.abc.LOCATION_DATA");
            LocationIntent.putExtra("lat", location.getLatitude());
            LocationIntent.putExtra("lon", location.getLongitude());
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
            sendBroadcast(LocationIntent);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Location returned NULL catching exception");
        }

    }

}
```

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Perfectly normal behavior according to the documentation: "The Intent supplied [...] **may be null** if the service is being restarted after its process has gone away, and it had previously returned anything except START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY" (source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: Okay, but how do I handle for it - so that it knows not to just crash the entire application?

Comment: `if ( intent != null ) { ... }`?

Comment: True I have that - but it still comes back with `thread exiting with uncaught exception`, and I am like but I thought I handled the exception?

Comment: a) There's no exception handling in the code you've shown, b) what is the exception? Logcat output?

Comment: So this is what I have in the logcat when I caused the error - https://gist.github.com/eWizardII/ce5ec5b89b8c9de88535

Comment: NullPointerException at `onHandleIntent(LocationIntentService.java:31)`. Now which line of code is that?

Comment: That was the `Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);` line.

Comment: No way this can be if you really did wrap the code in an `if`, like `if ( intent != null ) { Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED); ... }`

Comment: I agree, it would have just kept running since I handled for the `null` condition. So I am confused to. I'll just have it log the output of `Location location` and see if I can recreate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    //code
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Right. Why not be safe and write `catch ( Throwable e )` instead? - To me, fixing the error in the application logic seems more desirable than just ignoring the consequences...

Comment: True but in certain situations (you have to avoid them, but if you just don't know how) it is useable. I'm using it on a few occasions as well. And isn't a if(intent != null) just the same thing?